# How to development multi language application in spring?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to development multi language application. but I can't find detail information ve documents. How to get rows of current language data? When the user language changes, I want the data suitable for that language to come.

database model I'm considering
News
id
image
created_at
updated_at
NewsTranslation
id
title
description
locale
created_at
updated_at

Comment: have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization or here https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-internationalization/

Comment: These all read from property and usually apply to mvc. the rest api time I need to come from the database according to the language

Comment: it works similar for language texts from a database. 
what you have to do is load the text in the AbstractMessageSource from a repository.
see e.g. here https://phrase.com/blog/posts/database-stored-messages-for-i18n-in-spring-boot/